# Raspberry Pi cannot find file /dev/hidg0

Tags: raspberry-pi

I was following a tutorial on setting up the raspberry pi as an HID, more specifically, a keyboard. Other tutorials seem to work with the same file **/dev/hidg0**. I can't even find the file and I can't find any solution, since the internet doesn't have this particular information.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you and it took me a while to figure out.
I plugged in my device onto my mac and it's showing it as a RNDIS/Gadget, so I realize that it's something to do with the code I put in for setting up my pi zero as an ethernet gadget.

Just remove the code you put in /boot/cmdline.txt (the stuff after rootwait)